# Python pandas data frame fillna forward fill function not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

The fillna method of pandas dataframe is behaving in a weird way. I have a dataframe where the columns are of type datetime.date() and the indices are of type datetime.time(). On each cell I have values, and sometimes I have "nan".

Now the indices have a frequency of minutes, but some minutes are missing. For example, the time 7:18 does not exist in my dataframe. Now when I run the method fillna(method='ffill') on the dataframe, it generates the 7.17 and fills it with an absurd value.

**UPDATE**

In the new dataframe once the fillna is done, actually the 7.17 does not appear in the index, but if you look for it explicitly (eg using .loc), it has a value, which is plotted in the .plot() option...

I have also build my own fillna function manually, basically it goes column by column and fills the na with the previous value. In the debugging,  when it arrives to 7.16 it jumps to 7.18 like nothing has happened, because there is not "nan" in 7.16, neither in 7.18. But the result has the same weird value at 7.17, which does not appear in the dataframe unless you ask for it explicitly or you plot it.

Note that when I use fillna(method='bfill') the issue is not happening...

**UPDATE 2**

More things I discovered: if I save the dataframe once I have done the fillna to a csv, and then load it again, the strange value does no appear at 7.17. But if I parse the dates when I load the csv to a dataframe, then it does. Is not explicitly in the dataframe, but it appears when you plot it.

Anyone knows why is that happening?

Comment: When you say "timedate" do you mean Python's `datetime` object, or one of Numpy's time types, e.g. `np.datetime64`.  I've never heard of `timedate`.  It might be worth checking the dtype of your index and columns.

Comment: I mean datetime. I have more info actually, let me update the question.

Comment: It's usually better to show than to tell.  Instead of describing what's happening, if you can construct a small [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that other people can copy and paste, it'll be much easier to sort out what's going on.

Comment: I agree, but is not easy. The dataframe original source is a big csv file. I may try to do something smaller as an example and post it.

Comment: In fact in order to create an example I am trying to reproduce the issue with a smaller dataframe, i.e. a subset of the csv files that include the problematic numbers, and I cannot... so weird.